# compute max version on a vector

Tags: r, max, apply

I am looking for the maximum package version (ie using comparison function `compareVersion` instead of the usual `max`) on each row of a matrix. I could code a simple recursive loop but I am looking for a more elegant solution. I have tried `apply` with no success:

sample data set:

```
M=matrix(c("2.7.5","1.7.3","1.7.8","0.9-7","0.9-5","0.10-7"), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

what doesn't work:

```
apply(M, 1, FUN = function(e1,e2) ifelse(compareVersion(e1,e2)==1, e1, e2))
```

is it possible to avoid coding the recursive loop?

(Maybe first on the simple example x=c("2.7.5","1.7.3","1.7.8"), then I can easily apply it on all rows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best I have found is using the excellent function `Reduce`, which is doing exactly the recursive loop I was looking for

> Reduce uses a binary function to successively combine the elements of
>   a given vector and a possibly given initial value.

The simple case on a vector:

```
x = c("1.9-7","4.11-5",NA,"0.10-7")
Reduce(x=x, f=function(e1,e2) ifelse(compareVersion(e1,e2)==1, e1, e2), accumulate=FALSE)
```

On the matrix:

```
M=matrix(c("2.7.5","1.7.3","1.7.8","0.9-7","0.9-5","0.10-7"), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
apply(M, 1, FUN = function(x) Reduce(x=x, f=function(e1,e2) ifelse(compareVersion(e1,e2)==1, e1, e2), accumulate=FALSE))
```

Comment: Looks good, though the `accumulate=FALSE` is the default and doesn't need to be specified.

Answer (score -2):

Use the multivariate version `mapply`

```
mapply(function(e1,e2) ifelse(compareVersion(e1,e2)==1, e1, e2), e1=M[1,],e2=M[2,])
```

Comment: I don't think that would give the desired output.

Comment: indeed, that's not what I am looking for. I basically want to be able to identify the maximum of a vector, regardless of the vector size. In your case I am limited to comparing only 2 elements